# php mysql query getting only first value in column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name tblnetworkstatus and I have 11 columns

1. Id
2. issue_name
3. affected_server
4. affected_service
5. issue_type
6. priority
7. duration
8. status
9. start_date
10. end_date
11. description

I have following record in my table

```
id  issue_name         affected_server  affected_service    issue_type      
1   testing network     2,3             6,7                  failure
```

I am getting affected server and service id from the tblproducts and tblserver tables I have the following query in which i get only the first affected server name with id=2 and affected service name with id =6 I want to check both values for affected server 2,3 and affected service 6,7 I have the following query which i made kindly guide me

```
SELECT 
            m.issue_name,m.id ,m.issue_type ,
            m.priority ,m.status,m.description ,
            m.start_date,m.end_date,m.duration,
            s.name  as server_name,p.name as product_name
            from mod_networkstatus as m 
            LEFT JOIN  tblservers as  s  ON  m.affected_server=s.id
            LEFT JOIN tblproducts as  p  ON  m.affected_service=p.id    where m.id=1
```

from this I am getting only this result

```
issue_name          server_name     product_name    
testing network     Monitor Server  Amazon S3
```

But i Want both Monitor Server,server1 for server_name and Amazon S3,hosting account for product name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it-

```
SELECT 
            m.issue_name,m.id ,m.issue_type ,
            m.priority ,m.status,m.description ,
            m.start_date,m.end_date,m.duration,
            s.name  as server_name,p.name as product_name
            from mod_networkstatus as m 
            LEFT JOIN  tblservers as  s  ON  find_in_set(s.id,m.affected_server)
            LEFT JOIN tblproducts as  p  ON  find_in_set(p.id,m.affected_service) where m.id=1
```

Edit1:

```
SELECT 
            m.issue_name,m.id ,m.issue_type ,
            m.priority ,m.status,m.description ,
            m.start_date,m.end_date,m.duration,
            GROUP_CONCAT(s.name) AS server_name,
            GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) AS product_name 
            FROM mod_networkstatus AS m 
            LEFT JOIN  tblservers AS  s  ON  FIND_IN_SET(s.id,m.affected_server)
            LEFT JOIN tblproducts AS  p  ON  FIND_IN_SET(p.id,m.affected_service) 
            WHERE m.id=1 
            GROUP BY m.id
```

Comment: it gives me the possible result but in different row but I want in single rows with same columns server_name=Monitor Server,server1

Comment: use group_concat function to get results in same row.